# Given square matrix A, max angle between x and Ax

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is an arbitrary matrix (not necessarily a square matrix), I want to solve the following optimization problem:
$$
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \frac{\langle x,Ax \rangle}{\| x \|_2  \| Ax \|_2},
$$
namely, I want to find a direction $x$ so that the matrix $A$ could rotate the direction to the maximal angle.

A similar question is asked in [Maximum angle between a vector $x$ and its linear transformation $A x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266057/maximum-angle-between-a-vector-x-and-its-linear-transformation-a-x), in which, however, the matrix $A$ is symmetric. In this special case, the maximal angle depends on the condition number of $A$. I also wonder whether this conclusion holds in the general case that $A$ is non-symmetric.

Comment: A potential first step: let $A = U\Sigma V^T$ be a singular value decomposition. Note that
$$
\langle x, Ax \rangle = \langle x, U\Sigma V^T x \rangle = \langle U^Tx, A\Sigma V^TU(U^Tx)\rangle.
$$
So, setting $W = V^TU$ and $y = U^Tx$, we can rewrite this minimum as
$$
\min_{y \in \Bbb R^n} \frac{\langle y, \Sigma W y \rangle}{\|y\|\cdot \|\Sigma W y\|} = \min_{y \in \Bbb R^n} \frac{\langle \Sigma^T y, W y \rangle}{\|y\|\cdot \|\Sigma W y\|}
$$

Comment: Cool, but I have tried some similar approaches but got stuck somewhere. For example, we can write the inner-product and vector norm as the form of matrix multiplication:
$$
\frac{\langle x,Ax \rangle}{\| x \|_2  \| Ax \|_2}
= \sqrt{\frac{x^{\top} A^{\top} x x^{\top} A x}{x^{\top} x x^{\top} A^{\top} A x}}
= \sqrt{\frac{{\rm tr} (x^{\top} A^{\top} x x^{\top} A x)}{{\rm tr} (x^{\top} x x^{\top} A^{\top} A x)}}
= \sqrt{\frac{{\rm tr} (x x^{\top} A^{\top} x x^{\top} A)}{{\rm tr} (x x^{\top} x x^{\top} A^{\top} A)}}.
$$

Comment: So the problem can be re-formulated as
\begin{align}
&\min_{X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} \frac{{\rm tr} (X A^{\top} X A)}{{\rm tr} (X^2 A^{\top} A)}\\
&\mbox{s.t. rank}(X) = 1\\
&\qquad \quad~\, X \succcurlyeq O.
\end{align}
But I cannot figure out what conclusion this re-formulation can lead to.

Comment: I think you meant "max" not "min" ?