# Minimization of $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} \cos ^{2}x + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} \sin ^{2}x $

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

I was reading the answer in the post [Maximum angle between a vector $x$ and its linear transformation $A x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266057/maximum-angle-between-a-vector-x-and-its-linear-transformation-a-x/2281304#2281304).
I am not able to figure out how is minimizing over $x$ the following function
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} \cos ^{2}x + \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}} \sin ^{2}x 
\end{align}
equivalent to maximizing over $x$ the function
\begin{align}
\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\tan\:x\right)-x\right).
\end{align}
I tried using many trigonometric identities but could not figure out.

Comment: Using the half angle formulas and assuming $\tan \theta=a/b$ should do it.

Comment: I think there are some typos there. I think it should be $q_1 = [\cos x, \sin x]^\mathsf{T}$, $q_2 = [d_1\cos x, d_2\sin x]^\mathsf{T}$, then $\frac{q_1^\top q_2}{\| q_2\|} = \frac{d_1\cos^2 x + d_2\sin^2 x}{\sqrt{d_1^2\cos^2 x + d_2^2\sin^2 x}}$, it is not difficult to prove that $\frac{d_1\cos^2 x + d_2\sin^2 x}{\sqrt{d_1^2\cos^2 x + d_2^2\sin^2 x}} \ge \frac{2\sqrt{\frac{d_2}{d_1}}}{1 + \frac{d_2}{d_1}}$.